# Can't install or update packages like rlang in R 3.6.2; what am I missing?

Tags: r, rtools

I am on a work computer and unfortunately they are using an older version of R 3.6.2. I also have installed Rtools 3.5.

When running `install.packages("rlang")` and allowing compilation from the source I am presented with the following:

```
*** arch - i386
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc   -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I./rlang/  -o3 -wall -std=gnu99 -mtune=generic -c capture.c -o capture.o

make:*** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/etc/i386/Makeconf:208: capture.o] Error 217

ERROR: compilation failed for package 'rlang'
```

I have followed the install steps in the readme by setting up a .Renviron file with `PATH="C:\Rtools\bin;{PATH}"` and `BINPREF="C:/Rtools/migw_$(WIN)/bin/"`

I was expecting this to work, but nothing has been corrected.  I am unsure where to go from here.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow and R!  The current year is 2023, and the current R release is 4.3.1.  If you run that release, `rlang` will install without issue.  So please consider letting go of that R release from several years ago.

Comment: Hey there and thanks for the reply! I would like to but this is a work computer that has a lot of hurdles to jump through for new software.  This is what they already have available to me and I can't get this to work.

Comment: How about `install.packages("https://packagemanager.posit.co/cran/latest/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/rlang_1.1.1.zip")`

Comment: It looks like you are going to have hurdles in getting today’s packages running on an old version of R.  Pick your poison.

Comment: @langtang I tried that and get that it is not available for R version on 3.6.2

Comment: @KyleT - that `rlang_1.1.1.zip` link is literally the zip file of the package for R 3.6. You can just save and extract it to the R `library` folder and then use it (assuming you can grab any dependencies in the same manner).

Comment: cdalitz thank you, this was enlightening to me as well and proved to work.  However going to the posit libraries suggested by @langtang ultimately worked as well.  I just needed to install from that URL within the R terminal rather than RStudio.

Comment: As an additional update I have added the posit url as a secondary repo into rstudio and everything is installing now.

Thanks @langtang for the solution.

Comment: @kyle-t If you want to comment on an answer, please add the comment to that answer. Otherwise the author of the answer won't be informed about your comment. Glad that you could solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from addressing your specific problem, it seems worthwhile to generally describe the procedure how to install packages for older R versions:

1. Find the release date of your R version. This is printed by the R shell when it is started up.
2. Got to the archive link on the CRAN package site, e.g. for rlang to https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/rlang
3. Download a version close to the release date of your R version (slightly later versions usually work)
4. Install the version from the command line (the shell of your operating system, e.g. bash or zsh) with ("$" is the shell prompt)

   $ R CMD INSTALL package-version.tar.gz